# fonts-powerline apt packge conflict with `$_`

Tags: linux, bash, powerline

Whenever I run: `mkdir smth && cd $_` I get: `bash: cd: $'\E(B\E[m': No such file or directory`

I'm using a non-login shell:-

```bash
mkdir smth && cd $_
# Outputs -> bash: cd: $'\E(B\E[m': No such file or directory
type mkdir
# mkdir is hashed (/usr/bin/mkdir)
```

here's my [config file](https://gist.github.com/Aybak3k/eb9566053abc1f08c4fdfbc810840b2f)

if there is anything I haven't included or clarified, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem lies in these 2 lines in the config file

```bash
    none="$(tput sgr0)"
    trap 'echo -ne "${none}"' DEBUG
```

remove them

Comment: can't believe they forgot to remove debugging code mmm